# Plot initial data and predicted data (aima model) in R

Tags: r, arima

I have a dataframe and for example df[[i]] object:

```
c(0.115357, 0.081623, 0.064095, 0.037976, 0.034594, 0.072012, 0.062988,
0.029926,0.016034, 0.068849, 0.045474, 0.014287, 0.042347, 
0.012183, 0.007037, 0.010355, 0.035283, 0.006473, 0.003692, 0.002738, 
0.003707, 0.002289, 0.001643, 0.001023, 0.000878, 6e-04, 0.000851, 
0.000645, 0.000968, 0.000856, 0.000637, 0.00052, 0.000611, 0.000397, 
0.000193, 1e-04, 7.5e-05, 7.2e-05, 7.4e-05, 4e-05, 4e-05)
```

I try to plot data the same:
[image]

For my dataframe train data is:

```r
dfL_F[[28]][1:25]
```

and predict data:

```r
forecast1 <- predict(arimaModel_1, 16)
```

There is my code:

```r
arimaModel_1 <- arima(dfL_F[[28]][1:25], order = c(1,1,2), method = "CSS")
forecast1 <- predict(arimaModel_1, 16)
ts.plot(as.ts(dfL_F[[28]][1:25]),forecast1)
```

And I get the error:

```
ts.plot(as.ts(dfL_F[[28]][1:25]),forecast1)
Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, union = TRUE) : 
  non-time series not of the correct length
```

**How to plot different order ARIMA and intial data for my case?**

I'm sorry, but this post does not help solve my problems [Predict and plot after fitting `arima()` model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492428/predict-and-plot-after-fitting-arima-model-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forecast1` is a `list` of two elements

```
> str(forecast1)
List of 2
 $ pred: Time-Series [1:16] from 26 to 41: -2.62e-05 1.53e-04 2.36e-04 2.75e-04 2.93e-04 ...
 $ se  : Time-Series [1:16] from 26 to 41: 0.0167 0.0168 0.0171 0.018 0.0191 ...
```

It returns a `list` because the usage `predict.Arima` says

> predict(object, n.ahead = 1, newxreg = NULL,         se.fit = TRUE, ...)

where

> se.fit - Logical: should standard errors of prediction be returned?

Thus, by default it returns the standard error of prediction and if we use the full `list`, it returns the error

```
ts.plot(as.ts(dfL_F[[28]][1:25]), forecast1)
Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, union = TRUE) : 
  non-time series not of the correct length
```

We need to extract the `pred`

```
ts.plot(as.ts(dfL_F[[28]][1:25]), forecast1$pred)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have one question: se - what is it? I didn't see this opt in offical docs.

Comment: @Alex If you check `?predict.Arima` - `predict(object, n.ahead = 1, newxreg = NULL,
        se.fit = TRUE, ...)` where `se.fit - Logical: should standard errors of prediction be returned?`

Comment: Sorry for my inattention! Thanks a lot!